# Problem in Number theory proving a set is all the integer

Tags: number-theory

The question is there is a set $S$ such that

1. exist $a,b \in S$ and $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a-2,b-2)=1$
2. if $x,y \in S$, then $x^2-y \in S$
   Prove that $S$ is all the integer.

Use 2), by induction, i can show that if $1 \in S$, then $S=Z$.
But the I have trouble to show $1\in S$.

Comment: What does condition 1 mean?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @KentaS Oh, i am sorry. condition 1 means there is $a, b \in S$ such that $gcd(a,b)=gcd(a-2,b-2)=1$

Comment: See here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h54051p337875